# No OpenFabrics connection

Tags: python, fortran, mpi, openmpi, f2py

I am trying to run an ocean simulation with pyOM2's fortran-mpi component. I have thus compiled pyOM with Python 3 and `f2py`. This is all part of the [Veros](https://github.com/dionhaefner/veros) project.

When I run the benchmarks here with `fortran` everything works just fine. When I run it with `fortran-mpi` on my `AMD A10-7850K APU with Radeon(TM) R7 Graphics` machine (from `/proc/cpuinfo`) it works just fine.

Now I try to run the same file and configuration, but on a `Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2698 v4 @ 2.20GHz` machine. Here I get the following MPI error:

```
running benchmark isoneutral_benchmark.py
  current size: 980
   fortran-mpi     ... failed
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
No OpenFabrics connection schemes reported that they were able to be used on a specific port.  As such, the openib BTL (OpenFabrics support) will be disabled for this port.

  Local host:           scigpu01
  Local device:         mlx5_3
  Local port:           1
  CPCs attempted:       udcm
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  testing mpi routines
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
MPI_ABORT was invoked on rank 73 in communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD with errorcode 99.

NOTE: invoking MPI_ABORT causes Open MPI to kill all MPI processes.
You may or may not see output from other processes, depending on
exactly when Open MPI kills them.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ERROR:
  domain decompositon impossible in j-direction
  choose other number of PEs in j-direction
  global pe #          73  :  in pe_decomposition
  global pe #          73  aborting
... # From ERROR down it repeats 10-12 times
[scigpu01:58598] 79 more processes have sent help message help-mpi-btl-openib-cpc-base.txt / no cpcs for port
[scigpu01:58598] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages
[scigpu01:58598] 16 more processes have sent help message help-mpi-api.txt / mpi-abort
```

I have tried various settings for `OMPI_MCA_btl` environment variable, such as `^openib,sm,self` or `tcp,self`, but am not getting anywhere.

Any magic commands that I can run, for it to work on my Intel machine?

Thanks

Comment: try `mpirun --mca pml ob1 --mca btl ^openib ...`

Comment: That seems to have removed the "OpenFabrics" warning. The terms under "ERROR:" I believe comes from the actual implementation, and has to do with the fact, that the processor has 80 cores.

Comment: fwiw, `--mca btl ^openib,sm,self` means **not** `openib` **nor** `sm` **nor** `self` (and that will never work since you always need `self`)